# Showing same result in 2 URLs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to have URL which would have 2 forms.
1st would be: http://example.com/?g=123456 (123456 is code of gallery)
2nd would be: http://example.com/?g=Nature (Nature is name of gallery)

So, I have 2 tables: **gallery**, **photos**.
The **gallery** table has structure: id, name, description, code
The **photos** table has structure: id, p_name,p_description, gallery_code

To show photos in the gallery the `photos.gallery_code` must be the same as `gallery.code`
I tried this SQL:
`SELECT * 
FROM photos
INNER JOIN gallery
 ON gallery.code = '".$gallery_code."'
WHERE  photos.gallery_code = '".$gallery_code."' OR gallery.name = '".$gallery_code."' 
ORDER BY photos.id`

This SQL doesn't work. When I open the url http://example.com/?g=123456 the images that belongs to that gallery are shown, but when I open url http://example.com/?g=Nature every images that I have in table `photos` are shown(I don't want it).
I want when I open the url ...g=123456 the result would be the same as when I open ...g=Nature

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is wrong, try replacing

```
INNER JOIN gallery
  ON gallery.code = '" . $gallery_code . "'
```

with

```
INNER JOIN gallery
  ON gallery.code = photos.gallery_code
```

the rest looks fine.